# MySQL "simple" error understanding

Tags: mysql, syntax

i have a very simple request :

```
SELECT * FROM players;
```

which works and show a list of "players". 
Now if i do the exact same request on my table named "groups" i get a syntax error

```
SELECT * FROM groups;
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups' at line 1    0.000 sec

If I do :

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.groups;
```

It works 
and if I do :

```
SELECT * FROM `groups`;
```

It works too.

Comment: Is this query being run in a MySQL client (e.g., phpMyAdmin) or in a script for a web page?

Comment: are you running this inside a procedure? if so, do you have a parameter named groups that the procedure gets as an input? if this is the case then that is why the `groups` works for you.

Comment: I run it in mysql workbench.

Comment: groups is an protected keyword... since 8.0 Version, so you have to embed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUPS is a reserved keywords (GROUPS (R) added in 8.0.2 (reserved)) :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G

Answer (score 1):

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups' at line 1 0.000 sec

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) lists `GROUP` and `GROUPS` as reserved keywords, hence your query fails.